# Сохранение введенной информации в ячейках программы

Tags: c++builder, c++

Как сделать, чтобы введенные в специальные ячейки программы данные сохранились при выходе из программы и выводились повторно с места разъединения при запуске программы. При том была возможность добавлять новые, хотя этот пункт можно потом обсудить или же самому разобраться

Comment: Это называется persistence, гооглите.

Comment: Традиционное название этого механизма по русски - *контрольная точка* (check point). Обычно данные сохраняют в файле.

Answer (score 1):

У многих компонентов билдера есть метод типа `savetofile\loadfromfile`, позволяющий сохранять и восстанавливать введенные данные.

Пройдись по дереву компонента и отыщи его, обычно он во втором наследнике торчит.

Comment: тогда он при вызове покажет все данные, которые записались в прошлом сеансе? @Alex Dok

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли это возможно без записи данных в файлы. Программа существует в памяти только в момент ее выполнения. И при повторном запуске операционная система, вероятнее всего, выделит ей совсем другое пространство.

Comment: @carapuz, тогда так выходит, что без SQL никуда?

Comment: Безусловно, SQL тут самое оно, но кажется автор вопроса имел ввиду возможность запуска программы в том же адресном пространстве. Хотя может быть, что вопрос мною не так понят

Comment: SQL слишком **тяжелое** решение. Медленно и т.д.

Comment: @carapuz нет, я хочу создать локальное что-то. Чтоб данные хранились на одном(данном) компьютере и вызывались при запуске или же дополнялись. 
@avp а что посоветуете?